# FATAL EXCEPTION: main unable to start Activity componentInfo

Tags: android

I get the above error on the log when i click the button on my application. I will post the code for the MainActivity and the receiving activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)throws NullPointerException {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);

    button.setOnClickListener(onSave);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.calculate)
            calculate(v);
        }


    };
```

Calculate above on the onClick is my method that does the calculations, i'll post it below.

```
public void calculate(View view){
    Intent calculate = new Intent(this,Show_returns.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    EditText monthlySalaryString = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.monthly_salary);
    double monthlySalary = stripRFromInputString(monthlySalaryString.getText().toString());
    EditText ageString = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
    int  age = Integer.parseInt(ageString.getText().toString());
    double tax = ComputeTax.taxableCategory(age, monthlySalary);
    double annualSalary = monthlySalary * 12;
    EditText percInvestView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.perc_invest);
    double percInvest = stripRFromInputString(percInvestView.getText().toString())/100;
    EditText numYearsInvestString = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num_years_invest);
    int numYearsInvest = Integer.parseInt(numYearsInvestString.getText().toString());
    EditText lowTierInvestView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.low_tier_invest);
    double  lowTierInvest = stripRFromInputString(lowTierInvestView.getText().toString())/100;
    EditText medTierInvestView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.med_tier_invest);
    double medTierInvest = stripRFromInputString(medTierInvestView.getText().toString())/100;
    EditText highTierInvestView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.high_tier_invest);
    double highTierInvest = stripRFromInputString(highTierInvestView.getText().toString())/100;
    double lowTierInvestCompound = Investments.lowTierInvestmentReturns(annualSalary, tax, numYearsInvest, percInvest, lowTierInvest);
    double medTierInvestCompound = Investments.lowTierInvestmentReturns(annualSalary, tax, numYearsInvest, percInvest,medTierInvest);
    double highTierInvestCompound = Investments.lowTierInvestmentReturns(annualSalary, tax, numYearsInvest, percInvest,highTierInvest);
    String lowTierInvestString = String.valueOf(Math.floor(lowTierInvestCompound));
    String medTierInvestString = String.valueOf(Math.floor(medTierInvestCompound));
    String highTierInvestString = String.valueOf(Math.floor(highTierInvestCompound));

    extras.putString(LOW,lowTierInvestString);
    extras.putString(MED,medTierInvestString);
    extras.putString(HIGH,highTierInvestString);
    extras.putDouble(TAX,tax);
    startActivity(calculate);
}
```

Below is the code for the receiving activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent receive =getIntent();
    Bundle extras = receive.getExtras();
    String lowTierInvest = extras.getString(MainActivity.LOW);
    String medTierInvest = extras.getString(MainActivity.MED);
    String highTierInvest =extras.getString(MainActivity.HIGH);
    double tax = extras.getDouble(MainActivity.TAX);

    String TaxDisplay = String.format("Total annual tax amount is: R%0.2fc", tax);
    String lowTierDisplay = String.format("Compounded amount for low tier after 3 years is: R%0.2c", lowTierInvest);
    String medTierDisplay = String.format("Compounded amount for medium tier after 3 years is: R%0.2fc", medTierInvest);
    String highTierDisplay = String.format("Compounded amount for medium tier after 3 years is: R%0.2fc", highTierInvest);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(18);
    textView.setText(TaxDisplay +" \n"+ lowTierDisplay +"\n" +medTierDisplay + "\n" +highTierDisplay);
    setContentView(textView);

}
```

Here is my logcat.

```
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.investments/com.example.investments.Show_returns}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at com.example.investments.Show_returns.onCreate(Show_returns.java:20)
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-30 09:03:07.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat output

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace with your exception, if so post it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FATAL EXCEPTION: main unable to start Activity componentsInfo. caused by java.lang.NullPointerException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534102/fatal-exception-main-unable-to-start-activity-componentsinfo-caused-by-java-la)

Comment: Have you declared LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH etc as public static final Strings?

Comment: Please don't duplicate your questions. Edit the original with additional information.

Comment: You already asked this question a few posts down!!

Comment: I have declare LOW HIGH and MED as public static final Strings

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate of questions i removed the other one

Comment: I haven't caught the exception

Comment: Something on line 20 of `com.example.investments.Show_returns` is `null`. Which line is line 20?

Comment: line 20 is String lowTierInvest = extras.getString(MainActivity.LOW);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you are creating a bundle with the intent you sent but you never put the bundle in the intent so when you try to get it there is no bundle to get

you need to do `calculate.putExtra(extras);`

Comment: do i need to change how i get the intents?

Answer (score 1):

inside your `calculate()`, actually extras are not attached to the intent.Try

```
Intent calculate = new Intent(this,Show_returns.class);
calculate.putExtra(LOW,lowTierInvestString);
```